# Is a final variable instantiated everytime

Tags: java

When we have a final instance variable of a class, is it instantiated for each object created of the class or just created once and referred?
And what is the case if the final variable is a local class variable??

Comment: They are called "fields", not "variables"

Comment: You could test this by putting a print statement in the object's constructor.

Comment: @Bohemian - they are also called instance variables.  Oracle calls them that, so it is OK for us to as well; e.g. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html

Comment: Always write sample programs if things are not clear. The idea behind final will be explained, very well in any beginners book.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Final variables is instantiated for each instance of the class. The values once assigned to them may not be changed. These variables may be initialized once, either via an initializer or an assignment statement.

What you are referring to are the *static* variables. These variable is not attached to a particular object, but rather to the class as a whole. They are allocated when the class is loaded.

Taking these two together, you can have a *static final* variable for the class. This basically means that the value assigned to the variable *once assigned* is constant and that it would be attached to a class rather than an instance of the class.

Answer (score 4):

The `final` modifier simply indicates that the variable can be assigned *once* and never again. It has no impact on the instantiation; the rules are the same as for normal variables. All the `final` modifier does is prevent the value being assigned a second time.

Examples below.

```
private final List myList = new ArrayList();
```

The list will be instantiated each time this is run, i.e. each time the enclosing class is instantiated.

```
public void bob() {
    final List myList = new ArrayList();
}
```

The list will be instantiated each time this is run, i.e. each time the method `bob` is invoked.

```
private static final List MY_LIST = new ArrayList();
```

Again, the list will be instantiated each time this is run. As this is also a `static` field initializer, this code will be run when the class is first loaded. So, for simplistic programs, this will be run once -- in scenarios where multiple class loaders are in play (e.g. app-servers etc), however, this will be run once each time the class is loaded in a new class loader.

Answer (score 2):

Instance variables, class variables, and local variables are used to refer to three different things, so calling a variable an "instance variable of a class," or "local class variable" is confusing.

An instance variable belongs to an object. Whether it's `final` or not, space is allocated in every instance for it. If it's `final`, a value must be assigned during construction, and the variable can be assigned only once.

A class variable belongs to the class as a whole. There's only one variable, regardless of the number of objects of that class, and all instances can refer to it. Declaring a variable as `static` means that it belongs to the class. Like instance variables, a `static` class variable can be declared `final`. Then it must be assigned a value once and only once when the class is initialized.

A local variable is declared within a method, and the variable occupies space in the method stack frame—although that variable may hold a pointer to an object in the heap. Local variables can be `final`, which means they can be assigned only once. Also, if a local variable is `final`, it can be referenced by inner classes instantiated in the method.

Answer (score 1):

Variables are not the ones that are instantiated. Classes are instantiated. Variables are initialized. Instance variables must be initialized by the time the the object is constructed and if they are `final` you won't be able to reassign values to them. If it's an instance variable then each instance of the class will have it's own copy, otherwise if it's static then there will be only one copy which will belong to the class itself.

Comment: Yeah, but for non-primitive fields, the object to which it refers is instantiated.

Comment: @Bohemian: But still it's the object that is instantiated not the variable which refers to that object.